# Error message during calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Anyone, please take a look at my line of code.

```
int totalValue = 0;
    totalValue = int.Parse(Label9.Text) * int.Parse(Label6.Text);
    Label8.Text = **totalValue**;
```

Why I get error message?

> cannot implicitly convert type int to string.

Thanks for ya help.

Answer (score 4):

You should convert int to string. Something like this:

```
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

Or this:

```
Label8.Text = totalValue + "";
```

Comment: @gilly3: Which one won't compile?

Comment: @gilly3 Really? It works for me with .Net 4. Can you please show me compiler output?

Comment: @nikhil - The second one.  You can't use the `+` operator with an `int` on one side and a `string` on the other. Which operator would be used? Addition or concatenation?  That would only work in a dynamic language, like JavaScript. C# is strongly typed.

Comment: That's totally false. Here concatenation will take place. Why? Because when + is used between an int and a string, internally it calls like this `totalValue.ToString() + ""`. Try in your IDE and then tell me does it work or not?

Comment: @gilly3 Concatenation, obviously. `When one or both operands are of type string, + concatenates the string representations of the operands.` Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Wow. I learned something new. I'm surprised it works that way. Never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `totalValue` is an `int`.

Try this:

```
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int totalValue = 0;
totalValue = int.Parse(Label9.Text) * int.Parse(Label6.Text);
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

Comment: also, if you haven't taken care of it in another way your code will result in an error if the label contains a letter instead of a number.

instead of int.parse use int.tryparse(label9.text) this way, if the conversion fails, the result will be 0 instead of an exception

Answer (score 1):

**Using the text directly is not a good way, what if parsing fails?**

Use

```
int? val1=GetInt32(Label9.Text);
int? val2=GetInt32(Label6.Text);

if(val1!=null&&val2!=null)
{
int totalValue = 0;
    totalValue = val1+val2;
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
}
//You can also write your own logic on the TextBoxs if they did not contain a valid value by checking if val1 or val2 are null or not
```

Using the function to return int value if the input can be converted.

```
  public  int? GetInt32(string s)
    {
        int i;
        if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
```