# Error message (again)

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error message during calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753410/error-message-during-calculation)

```
int totalValue = 0;
    totalValue = int.Parse(Label9.Text) * int.Parse(Label6.Text);
    Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

Hi programmers. I can't  figure out why the above line isn't working. The above line gives me a runtime error that says; **Input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: `Label9.Text` or `Label6.Text` (maybe both) have not the right number format.

Comment: This means one of those text value is not a number (like "1234"). Maybe the "number" is too big to fit in int value e.g. "1245678987654321", or it has decimal format e.g. "1234.0", or it is not a number at all e.g. "1234s".

Comment: What are the contents of `Label9.Text` and `Label6.Text`, and what is your current culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i posted in the other question as well, try to use `int.tryParse()` instead, if something goes wrong it just returns 0 instead of that exception

like this:

```
  int a;
  int b;
  int.TryParse("a",out a);
  int.TryParse("5",out b);
  int totalValue = a * b;
  Console.WriteLine(totalValue.ToString());
```

this code will write "0" to the console, because it cant parse "a" to a string

```
  int a;
  int b;
  int.TryParse("5",out a);
  int.TryParse("5",out b);
  int totalValue = a * b;
  Console.WriteLine(totalValue.ToString());
```

this code will write "25" to the console, because it can parse "5" to an integer number

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you :) It perfectly works!

Answer (score 1):

It means one or both input strings wasn't of a valid format for parsing.

Check the values contained in `Label9` and `Label6` to ensure they are in the correct format and range.

Alternatively, check it as part of the conversion process:

```
string str = "xyzzy";
int num;
bool ok = int.TryParse (str, out num);
if (!ok) {
    // Generate error and return.
}

// Use num for whatever.
```

For your specific code, you could use something like (including an error indicator on the form):

```
int num1, num2, prod = 0;
LabelErr.Text = "";
if (int.TryParse (Label9.Text, out num1) && int.TryParse (Label6.Text, out num2))
    prod = num1 * num2;
else
    LabelErr.Text = "One or both input values are invalid";
Label8.Text = prod.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to parse the values und display an error if not possible, like I demonstrated below.

```
int totalValue = 0;
int firstValue, secondValue;
if (!int.TryParse(Label9.Text, out firstValue))
  throw new Exception("Text of label 9 wasn't a number);
if (!int.TryParse(Label6.Text, out secondValue))
  throw new Exception("Text of label 6 wasn't a number);

totalValue = firstValue * secondValue;
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```